# I am unable to get the icons from Font Awesome

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

//HTML code

```
<template>
  <lightning-card>
      <div class="icon-container">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i>
        <span>Email Us!</span>
    </div>      
  </lightning-card>
</template>
```

---

// JS code

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { loadStyle } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import FONTAWESOME from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/FontAwesome';

export default class MyComponent extends LightningElement {
    connectedCallback() {
        loadStyle(this, FONTAWESOME)
            .then(() => {
                console.log('Font Awesome loaded successfully');
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error loading Font Awesome:', error);
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: i have uploaded Font Awesome as a static resource and imported also but not getting the Icon.

Comment: Confirm that the @salesforce/resourceUrl/FontAwesome is correctly pointing to the Font Awesome CSS file in your Salesforce Static Resources?  Font Awesome has different class names for different versions. For example, in some versions, icons use 'fas', 'far', 'fal', etc., as prefixes. Make sure you are using the correct class names for the icons.

Comment: What do you get in the console?